# Why is my comment being rendered as a JSON object and not appended to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am creating a comment with Jquery and want to append it to the page without a page reload. I have a commentConfirm prototype function catching it before the post. I cannot use remote:true on this project so here is the code :

```
$(function createComment() {
  $("#new_comment").on("submit", function(e) {

    const values = {
      description: $('#comment_description').val(),
      rating: $('#comment_rating').val()
    };

    const newComment = new Comment(values);
    newComment.commentConfirm();

  });
});

function Comment(comment) {
  this.description = comment.description;
  this.rating = comment.rating;
}

Comment.prototype.commentConfirm = function(e) {
  let doIt = confirm(`You are about to comment: "${this.description}" and give a rating of: ${this.rating} stars`);
  if(!doIt)
    return;

  let params = {
    'comment[description]': this.description,
    'comment[rating]': this.rating
  };

  $.post(this.action, params).success(function(response) {

    $('div.comments_container').append('<div class="new_comment_' + `${response.id}` + '"> </div>')

      $('div.new_comment_'+ `${response.id}`).append('<h3 class="cheading">' + `${response.user.name}` + ' gives ' + `${response.rating}` + ' out of 5 stars! </h3>')
      $('div.new_comment_'+ `${response.id}`).append('<p class="cdescription">' + `${response.description}` + '</p>')
      $('div.new_comment_'+ `${response.id}`).append('<a class="ecomment" href="/recipes/' + `${response.recipe_id}` + '/comments/' + `${response.id}` + '/edit">Edit</a>' + " ")
      $('div.new_comment_'+ `${response.id}`).append('<a class="dcomment" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/comments/' + `${response.id}` + '">Delete</a>')

      $('form#new_comment')[0].reset();
    });
};
```

Not sure if this is causing an issue but here is my create function in the controller:

```
 def create
    if logged_in?
      comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
      comment.recipe = find_by_recipe_id
      comment.user = current_user
        if comment.description.empty? || comment.rating == nil
          redirect_to recipe_path(comment.recipe), alert: "Please fill out all fields"
        else
          comment.save
          render json: comment.to_json(only: [:rating, :description, :id, :recipe_id],
                                    include: [user: { only: [:name]}])

      end
    else
      redirect_to login_path, alert: "You must be logged in to comment"
    end
  end
```

Any help with his problem would be greatly appreciated!!

here is the repo if that helps answer some other questions: https://github.com/Bartekswistak/fun_guy_chef/tree/jquery

Comment: You need to check if your back end code is working.  Cause the ajax request to occur, and then check your browser developer tools network tab and make sure the ajax response is correct-looking.

Comment: @james This was all working fine, but then i needed to add the prototype to this app, so adding that in and moving stuff around has broken it. When I add in the preventDefault, is doesnt work at all, and with the code as is, Its reloading the page and displaying the comment in JSON rather than appending it directly as it did before.

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm the rest of your code is working correctly, but you will need handle the `submit` event manually to prevent the page from reloading...

```
$("#new_comment").on("submit", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) reloads the page. To stop it from reloading the page, [prevent its default action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). So, your very first function would look like:

```
$(function createComment() {
  $("#new_comment").on("submit", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    const values = {
      description: $('#comment_description').val(),
      rating: $('#comment_rating').val()
    };

    const newComment = new Comment(values);
    newComment.commentConfirm();

  });
});
```

Comment: @cantuket so when I add the preventdefault, nothing happens on the page, and I get a routing error in the console "404" no route matches, i know i tried this before with no luck.

Comment: I noticed you use $.post with a action that isn't defined anywhere. Check to see if the url it's reaching is reachable and it's doing what it's supposed to do. In the Ruby side unfortunatelly I can't help you.

Comment: Also check what @James above commented, since it's not reloading the page anymore it could help you debug where this is going

Comment: @James The request seems to be working fine in the dev tools, status 200 ok, its just redirecting to another page, rather than staying on the recipe page. It also seems like its not reaching the $.post code at all through the process, not sure why it isnt...tried adding a debugger with no luck.